Is ESD coating is necessary for payload fairing?
As per my understanding,a composite payload fairing have a cork tiles as TPS and than a top white coat for moisture protection. But is there any requirement of electro-static discharge coating as well to prevent it from static charge build up? Or is it not mandatory?
